# How to compare two times in Java?

Tags: java

I need to compare two times which would then give a user a specific access i.e. if the time is between 8:30 and 10:30 then the access is granted and the `system.out.println` would say "Access granted". Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You already have `isLate` and `isBefore` in your code. You only need to determine that both are false.

```
   if(!isLate && !isBefore ){
       System.out.println("Access granted");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), which seems to be your implementation (your code does not include the imports) implements Comparable, so you can just use the method [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#compareTo-java.time.LocalTime-).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the answer from awesome is probably a lot easier dont mind mine

Youre code is quite hard to read to be honest, considering the source code is not complete. Anyway, to answer your question, you should probably use the class [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) which Features a method called [after](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after)

Comment: why date and not joda date-time?

Comment: what do you mean by joda?

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar maybe because importing each and every library one can find on the internet bloats the program?